# Recursively building a hierarchy in linq

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

I have the following scenario: I need to display a list of all Transfers associated with a particular part going back through time. Transfers will have a "from" account and a "to" account as well as a part ID. I am provided the part ID and a account ID to represent the top of the hierarchy. I want to recursively iterate backwards matching the "from" account id to the "to" account id of another transfer. For example:

Given PartID 123 and AccountID a1, I return:

- Transfer1 (PartID 123, ToAccountID a1, FromAccountID a2)
- Transfer2 (PartID 123, ToAccountID a2, FromAccountID a3)
- Transfer3 (PartID 123, ToAccountID a3, FromAccountID a4)
- Transfer4 (PartID 123, ToAccountID a3, FromAccountID a5)

etc.

The catch is that there can be multiple transfers with the same ToAccountID and different FromAccountIDs.

I could do this easily in SQL with a CTE, but this is not an option right now. Is there a way to do this with a single Linq query or would I have to make multiple calls in a loop?

Comment: Do you have a small enough data set to just pull down the whole thing and handle it in your application code, rather than a query?  Also, what query provider/database are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately the data set is pretty massive. This is a SQL Server Db accessed via Entity Framework. The closest I have come as I mentioned is calling into a query object recursively, fetching the children of each element on the current "level" but the code is pretty ugly and not really performant.

Comment: Does it have to be LINQ?  Or can it be any method implemented in C#?

Comment: Also, if you were to follow @Servy's suggestion, you wouldn't have to pull down *all* of the data - just all of the `Transfer`s that belong to the given `Part`, and then recursively connect the transfers in the correct order.

Comment: Yes that is definitely an option. It does not have to be Linq necessarily but preferred to go that route if that capability was built in or easy to implement. (the scope of transfers involving a part is still an unknown - but probably manageable)